# WinSCP File >> Edit question

Tags: kubuntu, ftp, playonlinux

Using PlayOnLinux, WinSCP is installed and running. I have VScodium set as the editor for all files, but when I double click a file, codium opens a blank window. In the editor config, it has this command

`Z:\usr\share\codium\codium !.!`

It would appear that the filename is not being passed to codium or is being downloaded to a location that codium can't reach. How can I make this work?